# How to get the correct nested function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

I have this nested functions but it only called the first 2 functions and then skipped the others. Add it is too fast to redirect to another page. What I wanted to achieve is this and making sure that every instances finishes its job before proceeding to another instances:

Scenario:
First instance // first called
Sec instance // next called then 
Third instance // next called then 
Fourth instance // last called

May I know what did I do wrong?

This is what I did:

```
            if (db_name != "" && contact != "" && email !="") 
            {
                // createdb
                session.rpc('/custom/createdb',
                {
                    db_name: db_name,
                }).then(function() 
                {
                    console.log("Database created successfully")
                
                    //initdb
                    session.rpc('/custom/initdb', 
                    {
                        db_name: db_name,
                    }).then(function() 
                    {
                        console.log("Database initialized successfully")
                
                        // IT SKIPS HERE
                        //installapps
                        session.rpc('/custom/installapps', 
                        {
                            db_name: db_name,
                        }).then(function() 
                        {
                            console.log("Apps installed successfully")
                        
                            // AND HERE TOO
                            //createaccount
                            session.rpc('/custom/createaccount', 
                            {
                                db_name : db_name, 
                                contact_name: contact, 
                                email_from: email,
                            }).then(function () 
                            {
                                console.log("User account created successfully")
                            }); 
                        });
                    }); 
                })
              }
```

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, do you have some examples to show? I'm still new jquery pls bear with me :)
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write promise-based code that keeps nesting deeper and deeper, you're doing something wrong. Promises exist exactly to *avoid* this Christmas tree type of code.

Instead of nesting deeper and deeper, return the promises each of your RPC calls gives you. You also need to return the top-level promise from your worker function, so the calling code can wait until everything is finished:

```
function creacteAccount(db_name, contact, email) {
    if (!(db_name > "" && contact > "" && email > "")) {
        return Promise.reject("One of the parameters is empty");
    }
    return session.rpc('/custom/createdb', {db_name: db_name})                  // return here
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Database created successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/initdb', {db_name: db_name});           // and here
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("Database initialized successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/installapps', {db_name: db_name});      // and here
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("Apps installed successfully");
            return session.rpc('/custom/createaccount', {                       // and here
                db_name : db_name, 
                contact_name: contact, 
                email_from: email
            });
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("User account created successfully");
        });
}
```

Do the redirect in the calling code's `.then()` and the error handling in `.catch()`:

```
creacteAccount("myDB", "contact", "email").then(function () {
    // redirect...
}).catch(function (err) {
    alert("Could not create account! (" + err + ")");
});
```

Comment: It says here:
`Uncaught TypeError: creacteAccount(...).then(...).catch is not a function`

Comment: yes I did. This is the only changes that I made:


`creacteAccount("MyDB", "contact",  "email").then(function () {`
    `console.log("Successfully created your account")`
    `setTimeout(function ()`
    `{`
     `window.location = url;`
    `}, 5000);`

   `}).catch(function (err) {`
    `alert("Could not create account! (" + err + ")");`
   `});`

Comment: And when I removed the .catch() it just read the first session only and then redirect to another page.

Comment: this one, `var session = require('web.session');` . I'm calling every routes from a controller. Pls check this clip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5vqvEHxOoVnte75W9eNLYD4WqH57VJO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, i found out that it doesn't finish the process of 3rd instance. It just cut right away. Do you have any idea about a javascript functions which it should finish the current job before proceeding to another?